# Deserializing a struct with custom data types

Tags: json, serialization, rust, lifetime, serde

I am trying to `#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]` some structs that involve other custom structs, so I can transform them in and out of JSON, for example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Exercise {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub name: &'static str,
    pub muscle_sub_groups: [MuscleSubGroup; 2],
    pub recommended_rep_range: [u32; 2],
    pub equipment: EquipmentType,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Deserialize)]
pub struct SetEntry {
    pub exercise: Exercise,
    pub reps: u32,
    pub weight: Weight, // another struct with two: &'static str
    pub reps_in_reserve: f32,
}
```

…but I am running into this:

`error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter` 'de `due to conflicting requirements`

I've tried multiple different solutions online, including defining lifetimes and I've all but succeeded.

All of my code is [here](https://github.com/Zusier/wlrs) (sorry for spaghetti). The file in question is [exercises.rs](https://github.com/Zusier/wlrs/blob/0c1deb1c86c9067a67c6e476230426afc70157b5/src/exercises.rs#L18).

Comment: Please include all code necessary to trigger the error in the body of the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's possible to answer the question as-is, but it required to follow the link, which is not good for future readers. The question should have a self-contained example, not requiring to look the missing types up in the links.

Comment: Got it. Sorry it is my first time posting here, won't make the mistake again.

Comment: You can still edit the question to copy the significant parts from the repository. It'd be better if you do it yourself, so that we won't spoil the original intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimized example which yields the same error:

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Inner {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub name: &'static str,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Outer {
    pub inner: Inner,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd55e0e6ff2010cef6c27228cb692455)

To see what's wrong, let's look at the expanded code. It's rather large and not very readable, but even the signatures can help:

```
impl Deserialize<'static> for Inner {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'static>,
    {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Outer {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Inner` struct (the `Exersize` in original code) can be deserialized only when the deserializer (i.e. the source data) is `'static`, but the `Outer` struct (the `SetEntry` in original code) has its deserialization implemented for every deserializer lifetime - essentially, it implements `DeserializeOwned`, i.e. it doesn't need to borrow its data from anywhere.

Now you might ask, why this restricton? Why the `Deserializer<'static>` in the first case? The answer is - you asked for that, when placed `serde(borrow)` over `&'static str`.
When deserializing struct containing references, Serde has to prove that these references will never be dangling. Therefore, the lifetime of deserialized data (that is, the parameter to `Deserialize` trait) must be tied to the lifetime of original data - that is, to the parameter of `Deserializer`. And, if the struct has any restrictions on the lifetime of its contents, these restrictions are automatically transferred to the `Deserializer`.
In this case, you've asked for the strictest restriction possible - you've asked that the data being deserialized into `Inner` be available until the end of program. However, there's no such restriction on `Outer` - in fact, it can treat `Inner` as owned data, since this struct doesn't have any lifetime parameters at all, - so Serde asks for the most generic deserializer possible and then chokes when `Inner` requires it to be `'static`.

---

Now, what to do in this case?

First of all, you definitely don't want to use `&'static str` in any runtime-generated data. This is the type of string literals, i.e. of strings baked into the executable itself, not of the common-case strings.

The simplest and probably most correct way would be to replace any `&'static str` with the owned `String`. This will eliminate the need for `serde(borrow)` and make you struct deserializable from anything.

If, however, you want to use references (e.g. to eliminate unnecessary copies), you have to treat the whole structs tree as a temporary borrow into the deserializer - that is, you'll have the lifetime parameter tied to the `&str` in every struct which directly or indirectly contains that `&str`:

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Inner<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub name: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Outer<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub inner: Inner<'a>,
}
```

And then, when creating these structs manually with string literals inside, you can just substitute `'static` for `'a`.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you, I seriously mean it!